# Call a method right before start consuming Flux elements

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, flux

How to call a non-reactive blocking method in the API pipeline, but call it only if there is at least one item present in the Flux?

For example, before calling `itemsRepo.saveItem`, I want to call `setupRepo`, but only if at least one item is emitted from the Flux returned by `externalApi.getAllItems()`.

```
externalApi
    .getAllItems()
    .flatMap(item -> 
          itemsRepo
             .saveItem(item)
             .doOnNext(e -> this.logSaveResult(item, e))
             .doOnError(th -> this.logSaveError(item, th))
    )
    .subscribe();
```

Here are the relevant method signatures

```
Flux<Item> getAllItems();
Mono<Boolean> saveItem(Item item);
// The following are non reactive 
private void logSaveResult(Item item, Boolean isSuccess);
private void logSaveError(Item item, Throwable th);
void setupRepo();
```

Here is the complete code if you want to test it, but this repo has a little bit more than related to this question.
https://github.com/mps-learning/cassandra-save

Comment: For your Java questions, don't use the mono tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `switchOnFirst` like:

```
externalApi
    .getAllItems()
    .switchOnFirst( (signal, flux) ->
       if (signal.hasValue()) {
          setupRepo();
       }
       return flux;
    )
    .flatMap(item -> 
          itemsRepo
             .saveItem(item)
             .doOnNext(e -> this.logSaveResult(item, e))
             .doOnError(th -> this.logSaveError(item, th))
    )
    .subscribe();
```